# UL inside UL inside a foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, html-lists

I'm having some problems with a UL inside a UL. I'ts a dropdown menu, running on a foreach.

This is the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class='a1'>Menu
        <ul class="sub"><li>Sub 1</li><li>Sub 2</li><li>Sub 3</li></ul>
    </li>
```

And this is the PHP:

```
        if($result) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach($result as $r) {
                $i++;
                echo utf8_encode("
                    <li class='a".$i."'>".$r['nm_categoria']."</li>
                ");
            }
        }
```

I have no ideas how to do this.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? What is the output it's producing?

Comment: Show your $result array

Comment: could you post a sample of the structure of `$result`?

Comment: `<ul>` level may be gone for N level or it will be only of 2 level?

Comment: I'd start with making it valid against HTML standard.

Comment: @RobertPodwika which part is invalid html?

Comment: The $result returns the mysql query. i just need make a foreach inside a foreach, but, i don't want repeat the second "Ul".

Comment: Need to see the data that is used to generate the lists. I have no idea what field(s) are being used to store the data for the inner list(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use recursion:

$i = 0;
function makeUL($data)
{
    $menu= '<ul>';
    foreach ($data as $item)
    {
       $menu .= '<li class="a'.$i++.'" >';
       $menu .= is_array($item) ? makeUL($item) : utf8_encode($item);
       $menu .= '</li>';
    }
    $menu.= '</ul>';
    return $menu;
}

echo makeUL($result);
```

Now using mysql fetch result in 2D array like below

```
array(
             Menu0(
                   sub1,
                   sub2,
                   sub3
                   )

             Menu1(
                   sub1,
                   sub2,
                   sub3
                   )
             Menu2,
             Menu3,

             Menu4(
                   sub1,
                   sub2,
                   sub3
                   )
)
```